# Selenium WebDriver implicitlyWait

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I recently started development on selenium javascript webdriver. What I am trying to achieve is logged in to a website and then navigate to a different page. Following is my code snippet.

```
var checkPaymentStatus = function () {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.get('https://url/#/login');
    driver.findElement(By.name('username')).sendKeys('user');
    driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys('pass');
    driver.findElement(By.name('loginForm')).submit();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
    driver.get('https://url/#/report/advanced-options');
};
```

Above code is working as expected up to the login but issue is I am always ended up with not authenticated error when try to navigate to the **report/advanced-options**  and seems like implicit wait is not working or **driver.get** is executed before the wait. Any suggestions to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: implicitlyWait() is used to set the timeout for driver.findElement() /findElements(),  rather than for page load timeout.  The not auth error is due to you not wait the login complete, so that the server side have not inject the auto token into browser cookie before you open the next page.   remove implicitlyWait(10000) code line, add sleep 10 seconds. if sleep resolve the issue, you can change sleep to explicit wait

Comment: @yong yes sleep resolved the issue but I'm not clear with how to use explicit wait. can you please give me an example.

Comment: I think you can look the answer below  from Ratmir Asanov

Comment: @yong, yes got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits):

**Implicit Waits:**

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount
>   of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately
>   available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is
>   set for the life of the WebDriver object.

In your code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
driver.get('https://url/#/report/advanced-options');
```

You are simple calling a get, without try to find any elements.

With the [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

> An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition
>   to occur before proceeding further in the code. The extreme case of
>   this is time.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period
>   to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you
>   write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in
>   combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be
>   accomplished.

the example in the website is very explanatory.

So, after your login, you could wait (to an [expected condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)) for something that have to "appears" in your DOM before you call your:

```
driver.get('https://url/#/report/advanced-options');
```

Answer (score 0):

Today the syntax is:

```js
await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: TIMEOUT, pageLoad:
            TIMEOUT, script: TIMEOUT });
```